# How can i access my ubuntu server (with GUI) on another computer

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization

How can i access my ubuntu server (with GUI) on another computer? I have ubuntu server on my server but I just installed  ubuntu desktop to so I have a GUI to use. How can i use this GUI from my windows 8 machine? Do I use a KVM? I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable Desktop Sharing on your server and use a Program like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) to view and control the servers desktop from a windows machine.

To enable desktop sharing on your server, simply find it in the Unity dash.

Comment: What port do i use? As it wont let me connect

Comment: Have not done this in a while but from on top of my head: The default port used by VNC is 5900

Comment: i'm now getting a unsupported secuirty type message?

Comment: Can you try out the following ( from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233675) and let me know, so I can edit the answer accordingly. On a terminal run the following and try again: gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false